# Parse iOS SDK: Setting up Cloud Code in Terminal

Tags: ios, command-line, parse-platform, cloud

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ErjfPndGAt0) is the official video from Parse showing you how to set up Parse's Cloud Code on your Mac. I love how simple and well documented their SDK is to use, but this is a bit beyond my iOS only knowledge of coding. Furthermore there are several contradictions and confusions that arise from the set up process. I will detail below.

**1**) The first thing the video tells you to do is to open your terminal and type

[image]

This (from my iOS eyes) is a contradiction from what the [Docs](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#started) tells me to do which is type

[image]

there is a ~$ in front in the Docs version.

**Question 1**) What does the "~$" mean and why is it in the video and not in the Docs?

**2**) The next thing that confuses me is the video next instructs me to type

[image]

to navigate to my app. This is yet another direct contradiction to what the Docs tell me to do which is to type

[image]

**Question 2**) So which do I listen to? The video or the Docs?

---

**(If you answer any of these questions please let it be this one) Question 3**) Is "Geolocations" or "MyCloudCode" the name of the app that is being configured? So if I had an app named "FunnyPants" I would write either

```
~$ cd FunnyPants
~/FunnyPants (master *)$ parse new
```

or

```
$ parse new FunnyPants
Email: ninja@gmail.com
Password:
1:MyApp
Select an App: 1
$ cd FunnyPants
```

**?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll address the main question concerning your confusion with the `$` sign. You should post separate questions on Stack Overflow as they all could have different answers.

There is no need to type this symbol into your Terminal again as it should already be visible.  The dollar sign, `$`, in the terminal indicates that you're logged in as a regular user. If you were logged in as root, you'd see `#`.

It's common practice to include the `$` symbol to indicate which lines are commands that need to be typed in by the user, versus those that are output by the program. This allows docs to mix user input, as well as an example of what the command's output might look like, in a single block. For example,

```
$ parse new FunnyPants
Email: ninja@gmail.com
Password:
1:MyApp
Select an App: 1
$ cd FunnyPants
```

This indicates that the user should type in `parse new FunnyPants` which might result in an output similar to the next four lines. You'd then need to type `cd FunnyPants` when the `$` prompt shows up again.

Comment: You really cleared up the "$" symbol for me thank you! Kind of obvious now that I look at it. I am going to try and do what you told me and I'll be back and if I have any problems I'll ask again and if I get it working I'll put a check by your answer. Thanks so much.